# Como converter uma data (string) para um outro formato usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, data, rhino

Tenho a seguinte string:

```
2016-06-08 - 10:08
```

Preciso converter essa string para o outro formato:

```
08-06-2016 10:08
```

Como devo proceder?

```js
   function dateFormat(date) {
      inputFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
      inputText = "2012-11-17";
      date = inputFormat.parse(inputText);
      outputText = inputFormat.format(date);
      alert(outputText);
        };
```

Comment: Tudo que você tem é string, basta manipular e criar o formato que você quer. Qual código você tem até o momento?

Comment: Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Qual código você tem até o momento?

Comment: Atualizei @PauloHDSousa

Comment: De onde você tirou java.text.SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: é uma classe java. Eu uso o javascript Rhino, uma implementação java.

Comment: Da uma olhada nisso  inputText = new Date('2012-11-17');
alert(inputText.getDate() +'-'+   inputText.getMonth()+'-'+  inputText.getFullYear());

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Se sua string seguir o mesmo padrão, você pode mudar a posição das letras

```
var datas = "2016-06-08 - 10:08 ";
var novaData = (datas[8]+datas[9]+datas[4]+datas[5]+datas[6]
+datas[7]+datas[0]+datas[1]+datas[2]+datas[3]+datas[10]+datas[11]
+datas[12]+datas[13]+datas[14]+datas[15]+datas[16]+datas[17]);
alert(novaData);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p9u2w5gb/

Answer (score -2):

Porquê você não usa o método split pra separar a data pelo separador - e armazenar num vetor e depois só usa o método reverse() pra inverter o array e.e...

Comment: + 1 pelo esforço e argumentação. Precisamos disso aqui. Parabéns. A sua ideia é totalmente válida e coisa, inclusive umas das melhores, mas ainda preciso ter certeza da forma mais rápida, pois preciso realizar esse procedimento centenas de vezes em um laço.

Comment: Obrigado pelos comentários estou começando agora então realmente preciso das crítica e recomendações, na próxima resposta serei mais epecífico obrigado.

Comment: Oi Moisés, bem-vindo ao site. O ideal seria você [edit] e detalhar esta resposta, senão ela pode acabar excluída ou convertida em comentário. Aqui você sempre pode editar suas postagens para melhorá-las, incluir mais detalhes, a qualquer momento.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Vou detalhar mais em qualquer postagem.